# Looping on IEnumerator<T>, Any Suggestions

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I am having a situation where looping through the result of LINQ is getting on my nerves. Well here is my scenario:

I have a DataTable, that comes from database, from which I am taking data as:

```
var results = from d in dtAllData.AsEnumerable()
              select new MyType
              {
                  ID = d.Field<Decimal>("ID"),
                  Name = d.Field<string>("Name")
              }
```

After doing the order by depending on the sort order as:

```
if(orderBy != "")
{
string[] ord = orderBy.Split(' ');
if (ord != null && ord.Length == 2 && ord[0] != "")
                        {
                            if (ord[1].ToLower() != "desc")
                            {
                                results = from sorted in results
                                          orderby GetPropertyValue(sorted, ord[0])
                                          select sorted;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                results = from sorted in results
                                          orderby GetPropertyValue(sorted, ord[0]) descending
                                          select sorted;
                            }
                        }
}
```

The GetPropertyValue method is as:

```
private object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string property)
    {
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(property);
        return propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
    }
```

After this I am taking out 25 records for first page like:

```
results = from sorted in results
          .Skip(0)
          .Take(25)
          select sorted;
```

So far things are going good, Now I have to pass this results to a method which is going to do some manipulation on the data and return me the desired data, here in this method when I want to loop these 25 records its taking a good enough time. My method definition is:

```
public MyTypeCollection GetMyTypes(IEnumerable<MyType> myData, String dateFormat, String offset)
```

I have tried `foreach` and it takes like 8-10 secs on my machine, it is taking time at this line:

```
foreach(var _data in myData)
```

I tried while loop and is doing same thing, I used it like:

```
var enumerator = myData.GetEnumerator();
while(enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    int n = enumerator.Current;
   Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

This piece of code is taking time at `MoveNext`

Than I went for `for` loop like:

```
int length = myData.Count();
for (int i = 0; i < 25;i++ )
{
     var temp = myData.ElementAt(i);
}
```

This code is taking time at `ElementAt`

Can anyone please guide me, what I am doing wrong. I am using Framework 3.5 in VS 2008.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which implementation of LINQ are you using, if you're using .NET 2.0?

Comment: sorry didn't get your question, I am new to LINQ, so am not sure what do you mean by "which implementation".  Oh sorry, its not .NET 2.0 it 3.5

Comment: LINQ was introduced in .NET 3.5

Comment: LINQ was introduced in .NET 3.5. So you must be using something like LINQBridge (or another implementation) if you're using .NET 2.0. Likewise it's not clear which implementation of `DataTable.AsEnumerable()` you're using (it's a new extension method in .NET 3.5).

Comment: Ah. Okay, that makes a big difference...

Comment: I have modified my question and sorry for my mistake, its 3.5 not 2.0

Comment: Are you using skip to emulate paging? So next time it could be .Skip(25).Take(25)? How many rows in total do you have?

Comment: There are like around 300,000 rows in the datatable, yeh am using Skip and Take for paging.

Comment: @ImranBalouch You'll find it more efficient to page at the database level; if you show us the code for getting your data table, and also let us know the type of database server you are using, I'm pretty sure we can make this very fast. At the moment, you are looping through every record when building your collection of items (even though it doesn't look like it at first glance)

Comment: @dash, we are using SQL Server 2008, and in database SP was taking a good enough time, so I have been assigned to manage it at application level. And 300,000 is a subset of toal of 800,000 rows.

Comment: Don't use ElementAt - it will order the data for each result row = 25 times!

Comment: @ImranBalouch are you sure you can't do even sorting at the db level? They are really good at this. It's unfortunate that you have to load 300,000 rows just to get 25 at a time. Few people will probably ever page beyond say 200 so you're wasting a lot of system resources with the other 299,800 records per sort. If you can cut down the rows and/or do the sorting at the db level, you'll find life much easier - hope you find a solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: I suspect the problem is in how you're ordering. You're using reflection to first fetch and then invoke a property *for every record*. Even though you only want the first 25 records, it has to call `GetPropertyValue` on *all* the records first, in order to order them.

It would be *much* better if you could do this without reflection at all... but if you *do* need to use reflection, at least call `Type.GetProperty()` *once* instead of for every record.

---

(In some ways this is more to do with helping you diagnose the problem more easily than a full answer as such...)

As Henk said, this is very odd:

```
results = from sorted in results
          .Skip(0)
          .Take(25)
          select sorted;
```

You almost certainly *really* just want:

```
results = results.Take(25);
```

(`Skip(0)` is pointless.)

It may not actually help, but it will make the code simpler to debug.

The next problem is that we can't actually see all your code. You've written:

> After doing the order by depending on the sort order

... but you haven't shown *how* you're performing the ordering.

You should show us a complete example going from `DataTable` to its use.

Changing how you iterate over the sequence will *not* help - it's going to do the same thing either way, really - although it's surprising that in your last attempt, `Count()` apparently works quickly. Stick to the `foreach` - but work out exactly what that's going to be doing. LINQ uses a lot of lazy evaluation, and if you've done something which makes that very heavy going, that *could* be the problem. It's hard to know without seeing the whole pipeline.

Comment: I didn't put the ordering code, as things are working fine and kool till, the Skip and Take method. After this I call my method which I mentioned and in this method looping is taking time. However I am modifying my question to show that as well.

Comment: @ImranBalouch: Are you saying that without ordering it works fine, but with ordering it's really slow? Because the way you're doing ordering *is* very inefficient...

Comment: _Skip(0) is pointless_ - but `Skip(a).Take(b)` isn't. I assume this is for paging.

Comment: No, it has same behavior with or without ordering but still if you have time can you please also help me in the inefficiency of ordering or provide me some link for it.

Comment: @ImranBalouch: I've added an edit around the ordering side of things, but you should really identify *one* problem at a time. Without any ordering, this should be *very* fast. Can you create a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Yes, I'm sure it's for paging - but while the Skip is hard-coded to 0, it's just adding complexity with no benefit. When we've worked out why it's slow for just the first page, we can *then* add in proper paging support :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet   I have got little bit confused, when I have used this line of code, results = from sorted in results              
          .Skip(0)               
          .Take(25)              
          select sorted;

than in results there will be only 25 entities or all the 300,000 entities?

Comment: @ImranBalouch: There will only be 25 - but it's a *very* confusing way of writing it. Just use `results = results.Take(25);` to make it clearer. Note that it *won't* evaluate what those 25 are until you try to iterate over them.

Comment: @JonSkeet I sent empty string in orderby so that ordering code is not executed but still the looping in the Method is taking time.

Comment: @ImranBalouch: As I've said a few times now: please produce a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem. Just populate a `DataTable` with dummy (generated) data. Otherwise we're going to be asking questions forever, and not actually getting anywhere.

Comment: @JonSkeet Okes, I am going to make up a small program and will share it with you guys as soon as I complete it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13178/discussion-between-imran-balouch-and-jon-skeet)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your "results" IEnumerable isn't actually being evaluated until it is passed into your method and enumerated.  That means that the whole operation, getting all the data from dtAllData, selecting out the new type (which is happening on the whole enumerable, not just the first 25), and then finally the take 25 operation, are all happening on the first enumeration of the IEnumerable (foreach, while, whatever).

That's why your method is taking so long.  It's actually doing some of the work defined elsewhere inside the method.  If you want that to happen before your method, you could do a "ToList()" prior to the method.

Comment: I use .CopyToTable() but it also took time, I try this ToList() method as well.

Comment: Unless there's ordering involved (or something similar) it *doesn't* have to retrieve all of the data. Most LINQ operations are streaming - for example, if you just have a `Where` clause and you happen to only read the first three matches, the filter won't even be applied to the rest of the data. This is why the business about whether it's slow *without* sorting is so important. A sort requires all the data (as the very last item in the table could be the first to be returned).

Comment: (And no, "selecting out the new type" would only happen to the first 25 values as well, *if* there's nothing like OrderBy/Reverse/GroupBy going on.)

Comment: I could be confused about the ordering of the code segments in the given example, but there *is* an orderby clause involved above, and it looks to me like it happens before the method call that he's concerned about, and after the initial select to "MyType" objects.  To me that says it's going to evaluate *all* members of the enumberable before selecting out the first 25, because the "first 25" is dependent upon order.

Comment: @jdmcnair: You need to read the comments which state (repeatedly) that this apparently happens without any ordering. If your answer *depends* on the ordering being present, you should state that. "First 25" definitely doesn't depend on there being an `Order` call - you can just take the first 25 rows that the unordered DataTable returns.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Agreed, I should have mentioned that my answer was dependent upon the OrderBy, because it is.  In my defense, those comments that stated that the OrderBy wasn't necessary to duplicate the problem weren't there when I answered initially :)  And I didn't mean to say that the call to .First(25) couldn't happen without the OrderBy, I was just saying that *which 25* are returned is dependent on the OrderBy.  Anyway, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to adopt a hybrid approach;

In order:

1) Sort your datatable in-situ. It's probably best to do this at the database level, but, if you can't, then DataTable.DefaultView.Sort is pretty efficient:

```
dtAllData.DefaultView.Sort = ord[0] + " " + ord[1];
```

This assumes that ord[0] is the column name, and ord[1] is either ASC or DESC

2) Page through the DefaultView by index:

```
int pageStart = 0;

List<DataRowView> pageRows = new List<DataRowView>();

for (int i = pageStart; i < dtAllData.DefaultView.Count; i++ )
{
   if(pageStart + 25 > i || i == dtAllData.DefaultView.Count - 1) { break; //Exit if more than the number of pages or at the end of the rows }
   pageRows.Add(dtAllData.DefaultView[i]);
}
```

...and create your objects from this much smaller list... (I've assumed the columns are called Id and Name, as well as the types)

```
List<MyType> myObjects = new List<MyType>();

foreach(DataRowView pageRow in pageRows)
{
  myObjects.Add(new MyObject() { Id = Convert.ToInt32(pageRow["Id"]), Name = Convert.ToString(pageRow["Name"])});
}
```

You can then proceed with the rest of what you were doing.